# Could not convert from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to vector

Tags: c++, vector, initializer-list

The following vector declaration:

```
vector<string> valid_escape = {'n', 't', 'r', '0', '\\'};
```

Causes the error:

> `error: could not convert ‘{'n', 't', 'r', '0', '\\'}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’`

Other SO posts about this issue came to the conclusion that its a bug in 4.7 version of gcc or that an `-std=c++11` flag wasn't mentioned in compilation.

My gcc version is 7.3.0 and I compiled with the above flag.

Just out of curiosity and narrow hope I tried to replace `vector` with `list` and got a similar error.

Comment: `'n'` is a character, not a string. `"n"` is a string.

Comment: Okay, so you have described something that happened when you tried to write code, and the results of some research and investigation that you did. But what is your **question**?

Comment: Do you want 5 strings, each of size 1? Or a single string with 5 chars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a `std::vector` of `std::string`s intialized with a single `std::string` composed by those characters, you need an extra brace initializer:

```
vector<string> valid_escape = {{'n', 't', 'r', '0', '\\'}};
```

The inner brace will initialize a string with the given characters, the outer brace will construct a vector with that string at index 0.

If you want a `std::vector` containing several `std::string`s each one initialized with a single character you would need:

```
vector<string> valid_escape = {{'n'}, {'t'}, {'r'}, {'0'}, {'\\'}};
```

The `std::string` container has no constructor that takes a single character, hence the need for an initializer list.

Example:

```
string x = 'a';   // not possible, no constructor exists
string x = "a";   // possible, string(const char* s)
string x = {'a'}; // possible, string(initializer_list<char> il)
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` objects initialize with double `"` (double-quotes) like `"string"` not with double `'`(single-quotes) like `'n'`

try this:

```
std::vector<std::string> valid_escape = {"n", "t", "r", "0", "\\"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string as container for characters:

```
std::string valid_escape = {'n', 't', 'r', '0', '\\'};
```

Comment: or simply: `std::string valid_escape = "ntr0\\";` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I know but it's like `vector<string> valid_escape = {{'n', 't', 'r', '0', '\\'}};` in the accepted answer. You could replace it with `vector<string> valid_escape = {"ntr0\\"};`. It's more about the different possibilities to initialize a string.